# Two UILabels not aligning properly? iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I have two UILabels which I have checked have exactly the same properties in all the relevant ways but they don't seem to want to line up. I have set the NSKernAttribute of both to a value of 1.0 so it can't be that although it looks like spacing...

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

(Below are the two labels, and the properties for each of the labels)

[image]

**Shorter label:** 
Optional([

```
"NSFont": <UICTFont: 0x7f8e651542e0> 
font-family: ".SFUIDisplay-Thin"; 
font-weight: normal; 
font-style: normal; 
font-size: 30.00pt, 
"NSParagraphStyle": Alignment 1, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 4, Tabs (
    28L,
    56L,
    84L,
    112L,
    140L,
    168L,
    196L,
    224L,
    252L,
    280L,
    308L,
    336L
), DefaultTabInterval 0, Blocks (
), Lists (
), BaseWritingDirection -1, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningForTruncation NO, HeaderLevel 0, "NSShadow": NSShadow {0, -1} color = {(null)}, "NSKern": 1, "NSColor": UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.999462 0.999462 0.999462 1])
```

**Longer label:**

```
Optional(["NSKern": 1, "NSColor": UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 1 1])
```

Comment: are you using attributed string?

Comment: Yes, I set the spacing that way

Comment: Try to print out the attributes in code?

Comment: Could you print out the attribues for both and put it in your question, not in comment where it's harder to read it? You only show one I think. My guess is that you didn't applied the same NSKern at the same places. It' not for the same length.

Comment: I've added the printed attributes in the question now if you could have a look please?